# Interpreting Strace output to get instruction count of a process on Linux

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, strace, instructions

I have been trying to trace processes on Linux in order to find the instruction count for processes. I was suggested to use 'strace'. Now, strace gives a good trace of instructions, however I have problems interpreting its output to find how many instructions would it take for my application/process to run.

```
strace python MyApp.py
```

gives something like:

```
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5013, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 5
fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4398, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77bf000
read(5, "\3\363\r\n\365\"\21Xc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0@\0\0\0s\360\0\0\0d\0"..., 4096) = 4096
fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4398, ...}) = 0
read(5, "\0\0\0news\n\0\0\0algorithms(\21\0\0\0t\7\0\0\0_"..., 4096) = 302
read(5, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(5)                                = 0
munmap(0xb77bf000, 4096)                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat64( ......
```

Is there any way to see how many instructions are performed while the application is running?

I see there is instructions such as: open, fstat64,mmap2, close, read. I want to go to the level of assembler and check the instruction count. Furthermore, does anyone know the meaning of

```
<function_name>(<arg_list>) = <??THIS??>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: strace knows nothing about instructions; it just monitors system calls.  If you turned on timestamps (_-rT_ I think) you could get a vague idea of the number of instructions executed from the time delay between calls, but a debugger like _gdb_ would be a more appropriate tool for the job.  (The value after the equals sign is the return value of the syscall.)

Comment: As I now read it, GDB can only debug some languages, but not Python. Can you please give a little more information on how to get an idea of number of instructions using timestamps? Thanks.